# Parsing csv with changing timezone (due to daylight saving time) with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to parse a csv that looks like this

```
time                                val
28.10.2007 00:00:00.000 GMT+0100    1
28.10.2007 00:01:00.000 GMT+0100    2
28.10.2007 01:00:00.000 GMT-0000    3
28.10.2007 01:01:00.000 GMT-0000    4
```

To do so, I use

```
pd.read_csv(f,
            parse_dates=[0],
            dayfirst=True,
            index_col=0)
```

However, the result looks like this

```
                           val
time                          
2007-10-28 00:00:00-01:00    1
2007-10-28 00:01:00-01:00    2
2007-10-28 00:00:00-01:00    3
2007-10-28 00:01:00-01:00    4
```

This cause the 3rd and 4th row to be duplicated values. Is there a way to ask pandas to convert this time to UTC and understand the change in TZ?

Comment: how about changing the column data type after reading the csv, so first `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')` then you change the data type using `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`

Comment: @dzakyputra I did a quick try, but it doesn't work. If you know how to make it work, could you please show an example?

Comment: to clarify: a literal like `GMT+0100` specifies an offset relative to UTC but doesn't tell you anything about DST

Comment: By DST I mean that I need to correctly parse the TZ (that changes from GMT+0100 to GMT-0000 to avoid overlaps and/or gaps.

Comment: just wanted to point out that one needs to be specific here since this can lead to confusion ;-)

Comment: @MrFuppes edited the title to be more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this and somehow it works but I don't know if this is something that you want.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f GMT%z')
df['time_'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=True)
```

Comment: UTC is the way to go! The OP won't get "daylight saving time specified" since there is no information on DST in the input df strings.

Comment: By DST I mean that I need to correctly parse the TZ (that changes from GMT+0100 to GMT-0000 to avoid overlaps and/or gaps. This answer answers my question